# OSX partitions wiped by NAS RAID

Tags: macos, filesystem, data-recovery, nas, raid

So I messed up when I thought it would be a good idea to stick some hard drives into my NAS. It's now changed the partition table to a RAID0 one and my data has vanished. What are my best chances of recovering it?

Answer (score 1):

With the slim details you have provided, your best bet would be to seek professional data recovery assistance.

Most reputable companies will ask you what you have, what you need recovered and give you an estimate on the costs for recovery without needing to charge you for their time to understand the scope of the problem.

See:

- [Kroll Ontrack](http://www.krollontrack.com)
- [Drive Savers](http://www.drivesaversdatarecovery.com)

Both are highly capable at recovering Mac formatted media and filesystems. Additionally, they are fully professional in their skill at all other forms and format of data recovery. I've never regretted choosing either for recovery from personal up to enterprise needs.

Comment: Are there no software solutions that would at least let me see the sectors on the drives?

Comment: Any hex editor should do that limited trick. Try http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/0xed.html perhaps?