# Folders disappeared after I did something

Tags: macos, mac, finder, xcode

I was playing with the class templates for Xcode, and came down to [this git](https://github.com/borealkiss/Minimal-Template/tree/master/Minimal%20Template) and try to make my own from it as this is 2years old. And when I used this template, it never asked me for any details and immediately asked me where to save the project.. I selected Desktop and it saved the xcodeproj file on the desktop as Desktop.xcodeproj and deleted everything else on my Desktop. Sad to say ALL of my developing documents were on my desktop and it just disappeared. Not in trash can, not in .Trashes, not in Users/user/Trash, not anywhere on data recovery apps.

[This is the template PLIST I used](http://www.emotality.co.za/TemplateInfo.plist)

Comment: What data recovery apps were employed? This looks to be a simple case where deleted files have no backup and you might need to immediately stop using the computer and send the storage to a [data recovery professional](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89324/osx-partitions-wiped-by-nas-raid). Perhaps if you add in details we can link this to pre-existing questions that cover this ground or offer better guidance if it's not a case of the case where replacing a folder deletes all the files contained within.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, since a .xcodeproj is nothing else than a folder, that it may have replaced the original "Desktop" folder. Strange though, due to the different file extension...

As a second suggestion, have you tried `ls -l Desktop.xcodeproj/` ? This would give you the contents of the .xcodeproj folder. Alternatively, you could right click on it and select "show package contents". Maybe your original Desktop was just renamed and given an extension...

Comment: Hey, thanks for comment! There is absolutely nothing in that project, its a few kilobytes. :( And my Desktop folder is under my username like it should be. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don´t get the point. You did appearently not select Desktop as the folder, you gave the name Desktop to the project and created it in your home directory. What xCode does is, it creates a new folder which is called like your project, where your project is inside. The directory you actually chose to make the project inside is your home directory, `~/`. So xCode created a "Desktop" folder, and replaced the existing "Desktop" folder. No backup? Then I´m sorry to say: That data is most probably gone

Comment: If it is really important files, look for http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php . This program is able to recover completely deleted files, but don´t expect wonders.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was mistaken with the .xcodeproj ending. The XYZ.xcodeproj always resides inside a folder calles XYZ. So it was that folder that replaced your desktop. See my second Answer that is derived from this comments

Answer (score 1):

If you replace a folder full of files with an empty folder, the chances are 100% of the files are recoverable if you write no more data to the drive and get professional help recovering the files.

In practice, the OS writes files constantly, so there's always a chance it could extend an existing file and overwrite what was allocated space and is now seen as free space by the OS.

Your best bet if you truly have no backup is to stop using the computer immediately and get an estimate on the cost of recovery rather than learning how to do data recovery on your own data.

See the options in this answer for several good recovery programs and vendors (Drive Savers and Kroll Ontrack):

- [OSX partitions wiped by NAS RAID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89324/osx-partitions-wiped-by-nas-raid)

If you want to do a DIY recovery, I would buy an external drive and mirror the contents of your existing drive (not running that OS again) and attempt the recovery on a copy of the data. Again, it all depends on how much your work is worth and how much your time is worth so each recovery instance is a little different in weighing the costs to attempt a recovery versus just living with the lost files and starting over.

Answer (score 0):

You've checked your various trashes, which is a good start.  Have you tried a search via the terminal? I'd cd into Desktop/, then

```
ls -l .*
```

See if that turns up anything that might be hidden, including a hidden .Trash folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! All my files are unhidden. I did try your cmnd but returned nothing :( fml

Comment: Ok, getting into the danger zone a little bit, try `sudo find / -name "Desktop.xcodeproj"` enter your password when prompted, and see if anything appears. If not, then try various wildcard versions of your search, e.g., `sudo find / -name "*Desktop*"`  Best of luck.

Comment: Hey, the Desktop project file is what caused this to happen, its an empty project. I actually want a folder that was called "DEV" and got the following response with the cmnd you gave me above, you think this is it or something else?

JPs-MacBook-Pro:~ emotality$ sudo find / -name "Apptality"
Password:
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
JPs-MacBook-Pro:~ emotality$ cd dev
-bash: cd: dev: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You did appearently not select Desktop as the folder, you gave the name Desktop to the project and created it in your home directory. What xCode does is, it creates a new folder which is called like your project, where your project is inside.

The directory you actually chose to make the project inside is your home directory, ~/. So xCode created a "Desktop" folder, that replaced the existing "Desktop" folder. No backup? Then I´m sorry to say: That data is most probably gone.

If it is really important files, look for [Data Rescue 3](http://prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php) . This program is able to recover completely deleted files, but don´t expect miracles.